# How do I get the String in a JTextField from an action of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jtextfield

For a while I have been trying to figure this out, searching online, finally decided to join just to figure this out. So my dilemma is this.

```
addActionListner(new ActionListener(){
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //some code
}
});
```

What goes in some code that could actually pull from a JTextField (and for arguments sake let us call it myText)? Like how could I, if possible, call the ActionListner? so has when the button is clicked it actually performs the actionPeformed of the ActionListener in myText?

Comment: To get the value of `myText` JTextField, use `myText.getText();`.

Comment: You need a reference to the text field.  Then you simply need to call `getText()` on that reference

Comment: If the JTextField object is declared and defined locally within the method locally then declare it as final say like `final JTextField tf = new JTextField(10)` and then in `actionPerformed` getText using `tf.getText()`

Comment: add the same actionListener to both the textField and the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the action listener to the button and then retrieve myText's contents in the button's action listener. Hope it helps.

Assuming your button is named something like "myButton":

```
String someString = "";

myButton.addActionListner(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       //this will give you myText's contents. Do what you will with them.
       someString = myText.getText();
    }
});
```

Now you should be able to do whatever you want with the contents.

Comment: Thank you while looking at the api I totally overlooked the getText method inside JTextField

Comment: Ok it was in a separate class. What I ended up doing was basically making it a static variable in the main class and then accessing it like that, and doing something like `Main.myText.getText();` and it worked just fine